# Upgrading blackberry app installs as new App?

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to upgrade a blackberry app, but it is installing as separate app. What could be the problem? Both the app (older and new) have same name, and are signed with same keys. Any thing else am I missing?

Comment: Are you using the Eclipse plugin?  Have you changed anything in the BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml file, other than the version number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the same filename to the upgrade app as the old app has.

For instance if your old app has file name: `com_yourcompany_yourapp.cod` then your new app, if you want to rewrite the existing one must have the same filename. Application name in this context does not matter. Only filename does.